# Webview Content not using full width

Tags: android, html, webview

I am using a webview to load HTML content in my app. 
But text content is not using full width of webview, and it shrinks and wraps.

Below is code I have used:

```
webView.setInitialScale(1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);             
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

My HTML content doesn't contains meta tag for viewport.

Here is a Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Looking forward for help from you guys.

Below is HTML content:

```html
<p><span style="color:#c0392b"><strong>NYSBA Member: $175</strong></span><br />&nbsp;</p><p><img alt="" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png" style="height:250px; width:600px" /><br />&nbsp;</p><p><span style="font-size:20px"><strong>Estate Planning and Will Drafting 2018</strong></span><br />&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Program Description</strong></p><p>This full-day program will highlight current estate planning techniques and the means of implementing such techniques through a discussion of drafting of wills and trusts. Attendees will leave this program knowing how to write a basic will. Discussions will also include trusts for minors, charitable trusts, lifetime giving and planning for those with disabilities, tax implications and planning, digital assets, and ethical considerations.</p><p><strong>Who Should Attend</strong></p><p>Attorneys in the general practice of law, estate and trust planners, elder law attorneys, and those interested in a basic knowledge of taxation as it applies to wills and trusts.</p><p><br /><span style="font-size:14px"><strong>Sponsored by the Committee on Continuing Legal Education,&nbsp;the Trusts &amp; Estates Law Section and</strong></span><br /><a href="http://www.karpoffaffiliates.com/" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="{IMAGE URL}" /></a><br />&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Live CLE Program &amp; Webcast </strong></p><p>Tuesday, February 6, 2018 &ndash; Syracuse Sheraton University Hotel<br />Tuesday, February 6, 2018 - Long Island &ndash; Melville Marriott<br />Wednesday, February 7, 2018 &ndash; NYC (live webcast) &ndash; CFA Society New York<br />Thursday, February 8, 2018 &ndash; Holiday Inn Mt. Kisco<br />Thursday, February 8, 2018 - Classics V Banquet Center Buffalo<br />Friday, February 9, 2018 &ndash; New York State Bar Association<br />Friday, February 9, 2018 &ndash; RIT Inn &amp; Conference Center</p><p><strong>7.0 MCLE Credits: 6.0 Areas of Professional Practice,1.0 Ethics</strong></p><p><strong><span style="color:#c0392b">NYSBA Member:</span> $175 | <span style="color:#c0392b">Non-Member:</span> $275</strong><br /><strong><span style="color:#c0392b">Section Member:</span> $135</strong></p><p><strong>Agenda Topics</strong></p><ul><li>Estate Planning Overview</li><li>Will Drafting Overview</li><li>Planning with Revocable Trusts</li><li>Lifetime Giving, Minors and Incapacitated Beneficiaries</li><li>Tax Implications and Drafting</li><li>Digital Assets</li><li>Ethical Considerations</li></ul><p><span style="color:#c0392b"><strong>Program Chair</strong></span><br /><strong>Patricia Shevy, Esq., </strong>The Shevy Law Firm, Albany</p><p><span style="color:#c0392b"><strong>Local Program Chairs&nbsp;</strong></span><br /><strong>Jennifer M. Boll, Esq.</strong>, Bond Schoeneck &amp; King, PLLC, Albany&nbsp;<br /><strong>Gail M. Boggio, Esq.,</strong> McCarthy Fingar, LLP, White Plains</p><p><strong><span style="color:#c0392b">Buffalo Program Faculty</span></strong><br /><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><strong>Linda Stravalaci Grear, Esq.,&nbsp;</strong>Pfalzgraf Beinhauer Menzies, Buffalo<br /><strong>John F. Leone, Esq.,&nbsp;</strong>Gross Shuman, P.C., Buffalo<br /><strong>Kenneth Aaron Grossberg, Esq.,&nbsp;</strong>Phillips Lytle LLP, Buffalo<br /><strong>William D. Harrington, Esq</strong>.,&nbsp;Brown &amp; Kelly, LLP, Buffalo<br /><strong>Catherine B. Eberl, Esq.,&nbsp;</strong>Hodgson Russ LLP, Buffalo<br /><strong>Hon. Barbara Howe,&nbsp;</strong>Retired NY State Judge for Erie County, Buffalo<br /><strong>Dennis P. Cleary, Esq.,&nbsp;</strong>Duke Holzman Photiadis &amp; Gresens LLP, Buffalo</span></span></p><p><br />Newly Admitted Attorneys: To receive skills credit, newly admitted attorneys must take accredited transitional CLE courses in traditional live classroom settings that have been approved by the CLE Board for use by newly admitted attorneys.&nbsp; For more information about the CLE Rules, please go to <a href="http://www.nycourts.gov/Attorneys/CLE">www.nycourts.gov/Attorneys/CLE</a>.</p><p>Out of State Accreditation: This program has also been approved for MCLE credit by the State Bar of California, the Pennsylvania Continuing Legal Education Board and the Board of Continuing Legal Education of the State of New Jersey.&nbsp; If you require MCLE credit in other states, we can provide you a Uniform MCLE Form.</p><p>Partial Credit for Program Segments Not Allowed: Under the New York State Continuing Legal Education Board Regulations and Guidelines, attendees at CLE programs cannot get MCLE credit for a program segment (typically, a lecture or panel, of which there are usually several in a program) unless they are present for the entire segment. Those who arrive late, depart early, or are absent for any portion of the segment WILL NOT receive credit for that program segment.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong><img alt="{IMAGE_URL}" src="{IMAGE_URL}" /></strong></p><p>Follow NYSBA CLE on Twitter! <a href="http://www.twitter.com/nysbacle">@NYSBACLE</a></p><p>Stay informed. Be the first to hear about the latest course offerings.</p><p>To view the full list of Continuing Legal Education Programs,&nbsp;<a href="http://www.nysba.org/cle">click here.</a></p><p>If you have any questions about this program, please contact&nbsp;staff attorney&nbsp;<a href="">Sally Bratten.&nbsp;</a></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: will you provide url ?

Comment: Is the website you are loading responsive? I.e. if you went to this website using a mobile browser, does it scale properly?

Comment: Not used any URL, loading HTML content. I have added content used in my app in above thread.

Comment: Guys, I found solution to my issue. I have used android:targetSdkVersion="15" and have changed to android:targetSdkVersion="22". Working now. Thanks.